# Algorithm "brotliCompress" is not found in "zlib"

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, brotli

I have installed `compression-webpack-plugin` using [this](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/compression-webpack-plugin/) link and added Compression plugin in plugin section of `webpack.config.js` file as suggested [here](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/compression-webpack-plugin/#using-brotli)

When I run `npm run build` I am getting an error

> Algorithm "brotliCompress" is not found in "zlib"

I am using `node v8.11.3`.

Here is the full error

> C:\Projects\ProjName\FrontEnd\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\cli.js:93
> throw err;
> ^
>
> Error: Algorithm "brotliCompress" is not found in "zlib"
> at new CompressionPlugin (C:\Projects\ProjName\FrontEnd\node_modules\compression-webpack-plugin\dist\index.js:171:15)
> at Object. (C:\Projects\ProjName\FrontEnd\webpack\webpack.config.prod.js:67:5)
> at Module._compile (C:\Projects\ProjName\FrontEnd\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:192:30)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
> at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
> at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
> at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
> at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
> at require (C:\Projects\ProjName\FrontEnd\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:159:20)
> at WEBPACK_OPTIONS (C:\Projects\ProjName\FrontEnd\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\utils\convert-argv.js:114:13)
> at requireConfig (C:\Projects\ProjName\FrontEnd\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\utils\convert-argv.js:116:6)
> at C:\Projects\ProjName\FrontEnd\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\utils\convert-argv.js:123:17
> at Array.forEach ()
> at module.exports (C:\Projects\ProjName\FrontEnd\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\utils\convert-argv.js:121:15)
> at yargs.parse (C:\Projects\ProjName\FrontEnd\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\cli.js:71:45)
> at Object.parse (C:\Projects\ProjName\FrontEnd\node_modules\webpack-cli\node_modules\yargs\yargs.js:576:18)
> at C:\Projects\ProjName\FrontEnd\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\cli.js:49:8
> at Object. (C:\Projects\ProjName\FrontEnd\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\cli.js:366:3)
> at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
> at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
> at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
> at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
> at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
> at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
> at Object. (C:\Projects\ProjName\FrontEnd\node_modules\webpack\bin\webpack.js:156:2)
> at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
> at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
> at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
> at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
> at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
> at startup (bootstrap_node.js:191:16)
> at bootstrap_node.js:612:3 npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! ProjName@1.0.0 build: `npm run buildsprite && webpack --config ./webpack/webpack.config.prod.js --colors` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the ProjName@1.0.0 build script.
> npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely
> additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
> C:\Users\2048537\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2021-12-29T09_59_46_237Z-debug.log

This is how I injected the plugin

```
new CompressionPlugin({
        filename: "[path][base].br",
        algorithm: "brotliCompress",
        test: /\.(js|css|html|svg)$/,
        compressionOptions: {
            params: {
                [zlib.constants.BROTLI_PARAM_QUALITY]: 11,
            },
        },
        threshold: 10240,
        minRatio: 0.8,
        deleteOriginalAssets: false,
    }),
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like webpack team needs to update https://webpack.js.org/plugins/compression-webpack-plugin/#using-brotli link.

I replace plugin code as below as below

```
new BrotliGzip({
    asset: '[file].br[query]',
    algorithm: "brotli",
    test: /\.(js|css|html|svg)$/,
    threshold: 10240,
    minRatio: 0.8,
    quality: 11
}),
```

where BrotliGzip is defined as
`const BrotliGzip = require("brotli-gzip-webpack-plugin");`

then it worked.